# Ionic wont start after npm install ionic

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm

Im on osx. I had a development with node, npm and ionic. Everything worked.
I accidentally run this command:

```
npm install -g ionic
```

After that Ionic is not working anymore. if I try to create a project or start an existing one I got this error:

```
Caught exception:
Error: Cannot find module 'inherits'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/glob/glob.js:42:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3) 

Mind letting us know? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues
```

npm -v gives:

```
3.10.8
```

node -v gives:

```
v6.4.0
```

ionic -v 
gives the same error message as above.
Im not sure if I installed node/npm with brew or what else. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried re-installing?

Comment: If I try npm uninstall cordova ionic (both with and without sudo) it fails. it prints: enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/suername/package.json'. And then other error messages related to angular 1, like this: enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/suername/package.json'

Comment: I'll suggest using the commands in my answer below first. I.e. remove and purge your npm/npm modules, re-install npm then try reinstalling ionic again. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

in my case , uninstalling and reinstalling the ionic worked .

1.npm uninstall -g ionic cordova

2.npm install -g ionic cordova

3.npm update minimatch

4.try reinstalling ionic using ionic@latest

Answer (score 0):

This is because the module 'inherits' is missing which may be a problem with npm.

I'll simply suggest uninstalling and installing again as you may have downloaded corrupt/incomplete files.

On MacOS/Unix:

```
brew uninstall npm
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/node_modules/
brew install npm
```

Then retry installing ionic

npm uninstall -g ionic
   npm install -g ionic

Comment: I run the comands. After last ocmmand I get this: Error: Cannot find module 'are-we-there-yet'. Sigh.

Comment: Try: `npm i npm -g`

Answer (score 0):

Try again by adding  “read and write” permission  to your project root folder

Like

Ionic is my project root folder and under the ionic folder i have a app named ionicapp